# How to Check Data is Inserted Successfully in Firebase in Array

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am inserting some data in Firebase database From json Response in an array with below code

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
String[] stocks = new String[arr.length()];

for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){

   JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
   mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books");
   atabaseReference newBid=mDatabase.push();
   newBid.child("usr_id").setValue(obj.getString("user_id"));
   newBid.child("usr_fullNme").setValue(obj.getString("first_name")+" "+obj.getString("last_name"));
   newBid.child("usr_mobile").setValue(obj.getString("user_mobile"));
   newBid.child("usr_avatr").setValue(obj.getString("src"));
  }
```

How can i check if above operation is successful or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Hashmap` and do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> userValues = new HashMap<>();
  userValues.put("usr_id", obj.getString("user_id"));
  userValues.put("usr_fullNme",obj.getString("first_name")+" "+obj.getString("last_name"));
  userValues.put("usr_mobile", obj.getString("user_mobile"));
  userValues.put("usr_avatr",  obj.getString("src"));
```

Then use `setValue()`:

```
mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books");
String newBid = mDatabase.push().getKey();
mDatabase.child(newBid).setValue(userValues, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
           System.out.println(databaseError);
        }
    });
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#public-void-setvalue-object-value,-databasereference.completionlistener-listener):

> `public void setValue (Object value, DatabaseReference.CompletionListener listener)`
>
> Set the data at this location to the given value. Passing null to setValue() will delete the data at the specified location. The native types accepted by this method for the value correspond to the JSON types:
>
> - Boolean
> - Long
> - Double
> - String
> - Map
> - List

Comment: what is value at value.put, it is giving error can't resolve symbol value

Comment: how to use the setvalue() at the end it is giving same error as well

Comment: `new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
           System.out.println(databaseError);
        }
    });` this listener checks if data was successfully added to the database or not